# Rails 3 Route: button_to HTML INPUT Action not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, html-helper

I have a strange problem that I think has to do with routes.

In my "view" I have this:

```
<%= button_to "New Item", new_proposal_pitem_path(@proposal), :method => :get %>
```

I want to click the "New Item" button, and create a new pitem for a proposal. This generates the HTML I would expect:

```
<form method="get" action="/proposals/1234/pitems/new" ...><input ...></form>
```

However, what really happens is, when I click on the button it attempts a GET on /proposals/1234 rather than /proposals/1234/pitems/new. This gives me a "show" page rather than a "new" page. Interestingly, I can manually put the {site}/proposals/1234/pitems/new directly into the web browser HTTP address and get what I want (the "new" page). But rails is, on its own, translating it first to /proposals/1234 if I leave it to its own in response to the button click.

To make this more mysterious, I have a similar item on the same form which looks exactly the same way:

```
<%= button_to "New Payment", new_proposal_payment_path(@proposal), :method => :get %>
```

which generates the same HTML as the other case:

```
<form method="get" action="/proposals/1234/payments/new" ...><input ...></form>
```

But this one works! It takes me right to /proposals/1234/payments/new when I click the button, just like I'd expect. I just don't understand what makes these behave differently.

My full routes file looks like this:

```
TCoB::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :proposals do
    resources :pitems, :payments
    get 'list', :on => :collection
  end

  resources :pitems do
    get 'list', :on => :collection
  end

  resources :invoices do
    resources :iitems, :payments
    get 'list', :on => :collection
  end

  resources :iitems do
    get 'list', :on => :collection
  end

  resources :payments do
    get 'list', :on => :collection
  end

  resources :ids

  resources :clients do
    resources :proposals, :invoices
    # Route GET /cients/list
    get 'list', :on => :collection
    get 'list_proposals', :on => :collection
    get 'list_invoices', :on => :collection
  end

  get "home/index"

  root :to => "home#index"
end
```

Can someone shed light on this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: hint: check in your firebug where the button takes you (maybe there is a redirect in your controller?) the second thing that seems strange is that the url starts with proposal (singular) instead of proposals (plural). Double check your routes.rb - maybe there is an overwrite somewhere?

Comment: The "proposal" in the URL string is correct since it's referring to one proposal (#1234). Also note that this is totally symmetrical with "payments" which works fine. My routes.rb has very little in it other than what I showed plus indication of where "root" takes you. So I'm not overwriting the path. Finally, as I mentioned, if I type the URL in by hand, it works fine (I would think the routes would try to correct that, too, if that was the issue?). Since the HTML looks right, I'm still thinking it's a routes issue, though...

Comment: Sorry you were right. I had a typo. I corrected the original: proposal is pluralized in the URL. Also, no redirects in the controller exist.

Comment: ok... do you have firefox with firebug? Submit the form and check the firebug's network monitor where the form takes you, also have a look at the rails' log file, which controller responds to the request?

Comment: I have not used firebug before. I'll go figure that out and see what I see. "Rails server" does a little bit of spew and the first thing it shows is access to /proposals/1234, rather than the action shown in the HTML or the FORM item, the action being /proposals/1234/pitems/new.

Comment: you will love firebug ;) in the "Net" panel you can track the form request if it goes to /proposals/1234/pitems/new it's a server side problem (authentication? proposal not found?). If the form requests /proposals/1234 then it's a client side problem. I'm quite sure the problem lies on the client side because you said when you enter the url manually you get the correct page. Maybe you should try a `link_to` just to check if it's working.

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me on this, sled. When I click my "New Item" button, the rails server does a bit of console spew: the first thing it shows is 'Started POST "/proposals/1234"', rather than the action/method (GET /proposals/1234/pitems/new) specified in the HTML FORM item. It also (logically then) skips the 'new' method in the pitem controller and does an 'update' from the proposal controller instead. Still looking into firebug... but I know the proposal exists because the /proposals/1234/edit works, and if I put {root}/proposals/1234/pitems/new in the http bar by hand it works! (weird)

Comment: link_to works. button_to does not. The link_to generates "<a href="/proposals/4026/pitems/new">New Item</a>". The button_to generates an input button wrapped in a form (and the form has method set to "get" and action set as /proposals/4026/pitems/new). I am still completely baffled as to why my "New Payment" button works. From all I can tell, everything about it is identical to the "New Item", it's just another association with proposals. They're the same right down to the generated HTML.

Comment: ok so we narrowed it down: something is wrong with the generated <form> element, inspect it using firebug (HTML panel). Is the action set correctly? Is the method set to GET?

Comment: The form element generated for the button_to is: '<form method="get" action="/proposals/4026/pitems/new" class="button_to"><div><input type="submit" value="New Item" /></div></form>'

Comment: uhmm..... is the button inside of another <form>? Maybe the submit button triggers the "parent" form ;)

Comment: Yes, indeed. The entire proposal is itself a "form" and it's action is....(drum roll) /proposals/1234 (per my older example). Which seems to explain why New Item does what it does if it's reverting to the "outer" form, but now I'm wondering why New Payment works (since it is also a form within a form). And I need to puzzle through whether I can make a button, or whether I'll need to revert to a link. BUT this is huge progress!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small helper method that uses JavaScript:

```
def button_link_to(name, url)
  "<button type=\"button\" onclick=\"window.location.href='#{url}';\">#{h(name)}</button>".html_safe
end


button_link_to "New Item", new_proposal_pitem_path(@proposal)
```

Comment: sled, that's brilliant. I was just thinking about a javascript approach to get the button. The helper method is ideal. Thanks.

Comment: And I had to make sure to wrap the "button_link_to" in <%= raw button_link_to... %> :)

Comment: no need for the raw, I've edited the helper (just add .html_safe to a string to mark it as "safe") [more info](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/204-xss-protection-in-rails-3)

Comment: OK a new twist.... what if I want to pass a parameter, such as: button_link_to "New Item", url, :foo => @bar ?

Comment: url parameters or HTML attributes like `class` etc?

Comment: Yeah, what I want is my controller (called by 'url') sees param[:foo] as whatever I set it to. I can pass such params through 'link_to'.

Comment: nothing easier than that: `button_link_to "New Item", new_proposal_pitem_path(@proposal, :foo => 'bar')`

Comment: Ah ok. I couldn't find any documentation on that "path" method that said I could do that. Thank!

Comment: behind these auto generated path helper is the UrlHelper [`url_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html)